# Error with cwRsync on Windows 8

Tags: windows, rsync, cwrsync

I've installed cwRsync on my Windows 8 machine and tried to rsync files to remote server with the following command:

```
rsync rev/ user@ip:~/.tmp --rsh ssh --recursive --delete --delete-excluded --verbose
```

But get the following error:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(759) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Does anybody faced with the error above and what could be reason?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Where could I ask it?

Comment: I'd say that [super user](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to run this command as admin. Open your cmd as administartor and run again.